# How to remove red underline error in vs code, even though no error while compling

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

how to disable red undelines in vs code, i am getting this error

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I guess this errors are caused by the `eslint` and the type check from `typescript`. You can ignore those errors for the entire file by adding those comments to the start of the file.

1. `/* eslint-disable */` would ignore the `eslint` check for the entire file.
2. `/* @ts-nocheck */` would ignore the type check for the entire file.

```js
/* @ts-nocheck */
/* eslint-disable */
your code starts from here...
```

#### Reference

https://learn.coderslang.com/0023-eslint-disable-for-specific-lines-files-and-folders/
https://dev.to/evaldasburlingis/typescript-for-beginners-how-to-ignore-code-4han